# Rebinding 'this' for arrow functions in Node v7.9.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, arrow-functions

I want to pass around a function and rebind the `this`.  It works for some function types, but not others.

Here's my sample code:

```
class F {
  go (fxn) { fxn.apply(this, [1,2]) }
}

var f = new F();
f.foo = 'bar';
f.go(         () => { console.log(this.foo) }); // undefined
f.go(function ()    { console.log(this.foo) }); // "bar"
```

I understand that `this` is rebound to the caller's context in fat-arrow functions (and I'm so glad!).  I would expect the normal behavior of `.apply` and `.call` to override this and re-bind `this` at runtime.

My question is:  Can I re-bind fat-arrow functions at runtime in some way?

Comment: Arrow functions have **no** own `this` or `arguments` object. So you can't bind `this`

Comment: Ahh, ok.  I'll prefer to think of them as executable blocks rather than functions, then.  Thanks.